# How to add "excludeCategoryMask" for two different Categories in the same pass?

Tags: xcode, scenekit, arkit, metal, scntechnique

I have multiple Category Bitmaps.
I need it like that for other reasons. (ARKIT w/ SCNTechnique + Metal)

I have a SCNTechnique.plist with a specific pass where i want to exclude 2 specific categories, but i can't add 2 ***"excludeCategoryMask"*** in the .plist in the same pass.

Is it impossible to do excludeCategoryMask for two different category bitmaps for the same pass?

If so, it's kind of ridiculous, to have such limitation.